# Objectify Appengine should query a few rows

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Is there a way to load a fix number of recently saved rows/data using Objectify v5?

For example, I only wanted to load 10.

**Query**

```
HumanEntity human = ofy().load().type( HumanEntity.class );
```

What to add here?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
Query<HumanEntity> human = ofy().load().type( HumanEntity.class ).limit( 10 );
```